# Optimize calculation of number of weekdays

Tags: r

I want to calculate the number weekdays between two dates in R and I am using the following code:

```
Nweekdays <- Vectorize(function(a, b) + sum(!weekdays(seq(a, b, "days")) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")))

temp$diff <- Nweekdays(temp$from,temp$to)
```

This code works absolutely fine with a small data  (.1 million) but the code runs for hours on large data (5 million) and still doesn't get completed.

Please suggest way to do this calculation faster.

Comment: Out of interest, what are the ranges of `from` and `to` (i.e. min and max)?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternatives:

**1) break into whole weeks and fraction of a week** If the reason that it is taking so long is due to long sequences then this will ensure that the sequence is never more than a week.  Here `from` and `to` are the from and to dates:

```
weeks <- as.numeric(to - from) %/% 7
5*weeks + Nweekdays(7*weeks+from, to)
```

For example, with these `from` and `to` values it gives identical results to `Nweekdays`:

```
from <- as.Date("2016-03-27") 
to <- as.Date("2016-04-03")
weeks <- as.numeric(to - from) %/% 7
5*weeks + Nweekdays(7*weeks+from, to)
## [1] 5

Nweekdays(from, to)
## [1] 5
```

**2) precompute fraction of a week part** If from and to are less than a week apart then we can precompute all 49 possibilities in a 7 by 7 matrix `m` whose rows and columns are the day of the week of from and to (the first row is Sun, next is Mon, etc. and similarly for columns) and then define `Nweekdays2` which computes 5 times the number of whole weeks plus the lookup value in `m` for the partial week.

```
# precompute m
sun <- as.Date("2012-01-01") # any Sunday will do
m <- outer(0:6, 0:6, function(x, y) Nweekdays(sun + x, sun + y + 7*(y < x)))

Nweekdays2 <- function(from, to) {
  weeks <- as.integer(to - from) %/% 7L
  5L * weeks + m[cbind(as.POSIXlt(from)$wday + 1L, as.POSIXlt(to)$wday + 1L)]
}

# test

set.seed(123)
from <- as.Date("2000-01-01") + 0:99
to <- from + sample(100, 100)

identical(Nweekdays2(from, to), Nweekdays(from, to))
## [1] TRUE
```

Note that as an alternative to the definition of `m` above we notice that by inspecting `m` that it could be directly constructed like this:

```
Rm <- row(diag(7)); Cm <- col(diag(7))
m <- (1 + 5 * (Cm < Rm)) * (Rm > 1) * (Cm < 7) - (Rm == 1 & Cm == 7) + Cm - Rm
```

Comment: to and from are more than one week apart, almost 200 days of difference also exists in some cases, can I still use this?

Comment: Yes, of course. The whole point of (1) is to break it into the sum of two quantities one of which is a week or more apart and one of which is less. The first is just 5 times the number of weeks and the second is computed using Nweekdays from the question. (2) works the same way except it precomputes the key calculation in the portion that is less than a week apart.